# regular expression condition to remove elements

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the form:

```
var testStr="keyword:(test word) keyword2:(test word2) keyword3"
```

I am trying to remove all elements which comes before the `:` till a space occurs and after `:` till `)` occurs. so the *testStr* should only return `keyword3` for this example. The occurences of terms is not fixed. the keyword, testword can occur n number of times.

Comment: How about `/\w+:\((.*?)\)\s+//g`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
testStr.replace(/\S*:\([^)]*\)\s*/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var output = testStr.replace(/\w+:\([^)]*\) */g, '');
```